# Python daemon to watch a folder and update a database

Tags: python, database, filesystems, daemon

This is specifically geared towards managing MP3 files, but it should easily work for any directory structure with a lot of files.

I want to find or write a daemon (preferably in Python) that will watch a folder with many subfolders that should all contain X number of MP3 files. Any time a file is added, updated or deleted, it should reflect that in a database (preferably PostgreSQL). I am willing to accept if a file is simply moved that the respective rows are deleted and recreated anew but updating existing rows would make me the happiest.

The Stack Overflow question *[Managing a large collection of music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615565/managing-a-large-collection-of-music)* has a little of what I want.

I basically just want a database that I can then do whatever I want to with. My most up-to-date database as of now is my `iTunes.xml` file, but I don't want to rely on that too much as I don't always want to rely on iTunes for my music management. I see plenty of projects out there that do a little of what I want but in a format that either I can't access or is just more complex than I want. If there is some media player out there that can watch a folder and update a database that is easily accessible then I am all for it.

The reason I'm leaning towards writing my own is because it would be nice to choose my database and schema myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another answer already suggested [pyinotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify) for Linux, let me add [watch_directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/downloads/watch_directory.py) for Windows (a good discussion of the possibilities in Windows is [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html), the module's an example) and [fsevents](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-FSEvents/2.2b2) on the Mac (unfortunately I don't think there's a single cross-platform module offering a uniform interface to these various system-specific ways to get directory-change notification events).

Once you manage to get such events, updating an appropriate SQL database is simple!-)

Comment: pyinotify link is broken: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Answer (score 3):

If you use Linux, you can use [PyInotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify).

[`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) can notify you about filesystem events when your program is running.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best media player that has these features is [Winamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winamp). It rescans the music folders every X minutes, which is enough for music (but of course a little less efficient than letting the operating system watch for changes).

But as you were asking for suggestions on writing your own, you could make use of [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) (Linux only). If you're running Windows, you can use the [ReadDirectoryChangesW API call](http://tgolden.sc.sabren.com/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html#use_readdirectorychanges)

Comment: Can it connect to a database?  How can I access it's data?

Comment: Guess you mean the Winamp database?! It's stored in `~\Application Data\Winamp\Plugins\ml\main.*` (on Windows of course) and has a special file format described at http://gutenberg.free.fr/fichiers/SDK%20Winamp/nde_specs_v1.txt if you want to manipulate it - which you don't really have to, why would you want to edit the database if Winamp offers everything necessary?

Comment: I don't necessarily want a music player.  I am looking for a way to store all of my collection's metadata in a database.

Comment: Which doesn't really make sense if it isn't fully integrated with a media player.

Comment: What I do with the data is up to me.  Thanks for your help.