# importing updated files into a database

Tags: postgresql, streaming, data-access-layer, notify, listen

I have files that are updated every 2 hours. I have to detect the files automatically and insert the extracted information from them into a database.

Our DBMS is Postgresql and programming language is Python. How would you suggest I do that?

I want to make use of DAL (Database Abstraction Layer) to make connection between the files and database and use postgresql `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` techniques to detect the new files. If you agree with me please tell me how I can use `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` functions to detect the files.

Thank you

Comment: This question was also [posted on the pgsql-general mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/1345387783137-5720349.post@n5.nabble.com). @user1043898, please link back to a SO question when re-posting elsewhere, or at least mention you've re-posted.

Comment: Seems this question is actually a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314892/python-daemon-to-watch-a-folder-and-update-a-database, I only just noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to write a script that stays running as a dæmon, using a file system notify API to run a callback function when the files change. When the script is notified that the files change it should connect to PostgreSQL and do the required work, then go back to sleep waiting for the next change.

The only truly cross platform way to watch a directory for changes is to use a delay loop to poll `os.listdir` and `os.stat` to check for new files and updated modification times. This is a waste of power and disk I/O; it also gets slow for big sets of files. If your OS reliably changes the directory modification time whenever files within the directory change you can just `os.stat` the directory in a delay-loop, which helps.

It's much better to use an operating system specific notification API. Were you using Java I'd tell you to use the NIO2 [watch service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), which handles all the platform specifics for you. It looks like [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) may offer something similar for Python, but I haven't needed to do directory change notification in my Python coding so I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work out you can use platform-specific techniques like inotify/dnotify for Linux, and the various watcher APIs for Windows.

See also:

- [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)
- [Python daemon to watch a folder and update a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314892/python-daemon-to-watch-a-folder-and-update-a-database)

Comment: Thank you Craig. It was very informative. If I opt for using platform-specific techniques, could I incorporate them in python environment or I should use command line of the operating system?

Comment: @user1043898 You still haven't said what OS you're on, makes it harder to answer. **Please update your question with your OS**. You absolutely can use platform-specific directory watching facilities from Python, though it might take some hoop-jumping if they're only available directly as C APIs. A quick Google search found an inotify module for Python, and for Windows there's apparently http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: My OS is windows at the moment but I could shift to Linux if it is necessary.

Comment: @user1043898 Looks like there's some good info - for either platform, as it happens - in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314892/python-daemon-to-watch-a-folder-and-update-a-database). Between that and the links I've already given you I expect you'll be able to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use LISTEN/NOTIFY because that can only send messages from within the database and your files obviously aren't in there.

You'll want to have your python script scan the directory the files are in and check their modification time (mtime). If they are updated, you'll need to read in the files, parse the data and insert it to the db. Without knowing the format of the files, there's no way to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I actually know the file format and I know how to convert it to simple text files. The problem is detecting the newly updated files. Is it possible with psycopg or database abstraction layer (DAL) as database connectors to Python?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you connect to PostgreSQL, that's not going to tell you anything about unrelated files. There might be a library to do it for you, but otherwise just scan the directory for files and check the timestamps. Sleep 60 seconds and repeat...

Comment: Thank you. do you have any idea how to scan for new files?

Comment: Any introductory guide to Python should cover this sort of thing. If you don't already know a good guide will prove useful anyway.